# Why is there no output from this y/n program

Tags: c, string, conditional-statements, stdin

I have a problem with a small C program. It outputs a question (see code below) of which I can put input into (y and n) but then nothing else happens, even though it is meant to print something according to the input entered (y or n). However, nothing is outputted after my question, and the program just exits. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char string [80];
        static char y;
        static char n;
        printf( "ARE YOU SHAQIRI? [y/n]: " );
        scanf( "%s", string );
        if ("%s" == "y")
                printf("That's impossible. YOU CANNOT BE SHAQIRI YOU IDIOT");
        else if ("%s" == "n")
              printf("I thought not.");
        fflush ( stdin );
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why waste the 80 bytes for a string when a single char is all that's required for a y/n response? Just `getchar()` instead of `scanf()`

Comment: Never call `fflush` on `stdin` - it results in Undefined Behaviour. Also, why are you making your local variables `static` ?

Comment: Here's the fundamental error: *"%s"* is not magical.  It's just the literal string with a percent sign and an s.  So *"%s" == "y"* will always be false, as will *"%s" == "n"*.

Comment: See also [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems in your comparison: `if ("%s" == "y")`:

- `"%s"` is your `scanf` *format string*. If `scanf` succeeds in reading the input, then the result is in your variable: `string`.
- Don't use `==` to compare strings. You should use `strcmp`.

Because you use a comparison of this form in both `if` tests, neither branch executes, and you see no output.

Also don't call `fflush` on `stdin`. You may intend `fflush(stdout)` there.

Comment: OK, so after modifying the program from this and also using Mike's example, the linker throws out a mental error - http://pastebin.com/QA3eFHiR

Comment: OK, so my big error has turned into a small one (I needed to include stdlib.h and string.h:)
`shaqiri.c:10:13: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
shaqiri.c:12:18: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
`

Comment: @islandmonkey look at your `strcmp` call: `(strcmp "input", n)`. You have problems there: 1) not a valid function call; 2) the bare `n` isn't a variable or a string. Don't you want `"n"` there?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you compare strings in C, you need to use `strcmp`. Also, you need to compare the variable `string`, not `"%s"`.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` stores the returned values in the second parameter. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/). Second you're compairing the strings wrong... use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/)

I'm just going to throw this out there as a simplification to your program:

1. using a single char to store the single char input
2. you get to keep your conditionals the way you wanted them now "=="
3. removed the fflush of stdin, you shouldn't be doing that anyway.
4. added a "catch all" case for non 'y'/'n' input values.

Here's the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int main() {
    char input;
    printf( "ARE YOU SHAQIRI? [y/n]: " );
    input = getchar();
    if (input == 'y')
        printf("That's impossible. YOU CANNOT BE SHAQIRI YOU IDIOT");
    else if (input == 'n')
        printf("I thought not.");
    else
        printf("Not valid input...");
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have built in operators for comparing char arrays, therefore you call `strcmp`, like this:

```
if(strcmp(string, "yes") == ) 
{
    /* User said yes */
}
```

Make sure to `#include <string.h>`